# How to Identify whether the function is communicated either synchronous or Asynchronous?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, synchronous

I am working in Angular 8.I am using subscribe to get the data from the server.How to identify that it is communicated synchronously or asynchronously.If suppose that is Asynchronous how to make it synchronous and vice versa.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: AJAX calls are always asynchronous you cannot make it synchronous. Add your code and explain what you are trying to do, there should be an asynchronous way of doing it.

Comment: Always can convert a function that return a value in an Observable using 'rxjs' operator `of`, e.g. `myFunction():Observable<string>{ return of("hello word")}`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for this: https://javascript.info/async-await

You can convert an asynchronous into synchronous. e.g:

```
const getData = async() => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('https://sample.com/api/v1');
    // process the response data
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Comment: The async keyword doesn't make the function synchronous, the return result stays a promise, but it allows you to write your code more easily than then callbacks

Comment: Is subscribe for synchronous or asynchronous?